Artifactory migration to new node with single license
I'm following JFrog's knowledge base article for migrating Artifactory to a new node - https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime.
When starting up Artifactory on the new node and running through the startup wizard, it's requesting the license key.
I only have one license key. Would I remain within the T&C's by stopping the Artifactory service on the old node and using the license to get the new node up, and then stopping  Artifactory on this new node and restarting on the old one whilst I rsync everything across?
I have searched here and elsewhere online, but have not been successful finding any information regarding Pro licensing and whether installing the same license on more than one node is permitted, even if only one instance of the Artifactory service is up and running at any given time.
Thanks.

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

...because I was told with was a technical support issue, not CS.

How is this is a technical issue? You are asking if this is in line with the T&C. We can't answer that, see the article above. SO is a Q&A website for programming-related issues.

We can migrate from one instance to another instance using a single license, however, it requires downtime since we cannot have two different instances running with the same licenses which is a violation of EULA. I can suggest the following two approaches.
Approach 1:

Stop the live traffic to the current instance
Perform the full system export with include content option(recommended for small-scale systems). If it is a large-scale system, copy the filestore(Ex: NFS, S3)in the backend to the new environment and perform the system export without content on the existing Artifactory instance.
Shutdown the current system
Take the license from the current system and put it in the new environment and bring it up
Import the content from Step 2 to the new environment.

Approach2:
If there is an external database(Ex: PostgreSQL) and filestore(Ex: S3) then bring up the new environment with the same version of these products.

Stop the live traffic to the current instance
Copy the filestore(S3) on the backend
Perform the database dump from the existing system to the new system and do not start the instance
Shutdown the existing system and get its license and put it in the new environment
Bring up the new environment.

I recommended testing these scenarios in a non-prod/test/lower environment and defining a game plan for production activity.
If you cannot afford any downtime in the current environment, kindly contact the JFrog Support(for technical queries)/Sales(for License queries) team for help.

As I understand it, this seems broadly in-line with the knowledge base article provided above.  The key point here is that two instances of Artifactory cannot be running on the one license at the same time?  As long as only one is active for purposes of migrating, we are covered?

Only one unique license should be active on a running system at any given time.
